# Firebase is authorised by FedRAMP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am using Firebase as back end. I saw google service was authorised by FedRAMP and firebase has been used integrating with google cloud.
So firebase is also authorised by FedRAMP? If not, is there any way to be authorised by FedRAMP in firebase?

Answer (score 1):

@Tahvo., I too am developing on Firebase and Cloud Firestore within the Gov. I talked to our Google Rep and she queried the Federal team within Google. Apparently firebase didn't go through the Fedramp certification but there are plans (according to my Google Rep) to add this in the future. I could not get a estimated date/time. Its too bad because it would be nice to store data without worry about ports etc.

Comment: Yes, it looks like Cloud Firestore is now part of the Fedramp approvals. see here: https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/fedramp

Comment: @Fergus does Cloud Firestore mean all of Firebase, including Crashlytics, RemoteConfig, and push notifications, are FedRamp compliant?

Comment: @scaly, It does, in-fact all of the firebase/firestore offerings look to be approved. But to develop on the platform you still have to go through the (not so easy) the RMF process (https://tailored.fedramp.gov/)..

Comment: @Fergus where do we look exactly within the Google Fedramp page for compliance of particular components? I'm looking for Firebase.

Comment: @David, depending on the category, agency or IL levels. But this is a good place to start: https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance You can also call them: 844-613-7589